# Definite positive matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

According to a book that I have an hermitian matrix is definite positive if $X^TA\overline{X}>0$, but here in the forums (and other sources) the definition is given by $X^*AX>0$.

Somehow I'm failing to prove that these two definitions are equivalent. Can someone please explain me this?

Comment: If you are dealing with *real* matrices, they are equivalent. But not for complex matrices. (Note that $X^T = X^*$ if $X$ is a real matrix.) Are you dealing with real matrices?

Comment: But an hermitian matrix is a complex matrix. That's where I'm struggling...

Comment: For real matrices, you will be looking at *symmetric* matrices. In the real case, you can just use the transpose $(X^T)$, but if you're dealing with complex matrices, you must use the adjoint $(X^*)$.

Comment: I corrected a mistake in the initial post. What I'm thinking is that $X^T A\overline{X}=X^*AX$, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of mixed up quantifiers.

The one source says (or meant to say, or should say, or did say and the OP miscopied) that a Hermitian matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if for each nonzero vector $X$, we have the inequality $X^TA\overline X>0$.  Similarly, the other source says the condition is that for all nonzero  $Y$ you have $Y^* A Y>0$, where I have taken the liberty of renaming variables for clarity.

Now the resolution is clear: the two conditions are the same, if you let the second source's $Y$ equal $\overline X$.  If you know the one inequality for all $X\ne0$ you know the other for all $Y\ne0$, and vice versa.